# How to run animation via Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an animation in CSS that is a '-moz-keyframe' animation.  I can't seem to find any function in Javascript that will run the animation.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is Mozilla CSS. You don't need to have a JS code for this animation. Just use the CSS attribute on the element. Check out this example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/animations/cssanim1.html

You can check more information at [Mozilla CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations)

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS class that contains nothing but the rules for the animation. Then just add/remove that class with JavaScript.